# Why "all" is giving me this "Couldn't match expected type"?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, matrix

```
m = [[1,0,0],[2,-3,0],[4,5]]
t all@(x:xs) = let (m, n) = (length all, length x) in all (==n) (map length all)
```

The command:

```
t m
```

gives:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> t'
       against inferred type `[[a]]'
In the expression: all (== n) (map length all)
In the expression:
    let (m, n) = (length all, length x) in all (== n) (map length all)
In the definition of `t':
    t (all@(x : xs))
           = let (m, n) = ... in all (== n) (map length all)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is, that you redefine the symbol `all` to the parameter of `t`. Thus, the local `all` shadows the global `all` and you get this error. As a solution, try to give your local `all` another name.

Answer (score 4):

You bind the name `all` to the whole list, so the prelude function `all` is no longer visible. Choose a different name, or drop the `all@` and just use `let (m, n) = (length xs + 1, ...)` or something similar.

Relatedly: Why do you calculare `length all` at all? You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: I was thinking that Haskell were smart enough to understand different semantic of "all" apart from shadowing. Sad. Thanks

Comment: @Gremo: Is it supposed to *guess* which of the potentially many `all` you meant? One name refers to one thing and that's a good thing - good for the complexity budget, good for simplicity, good for reasoning over code.

Comment: @delnan: It's just on step in my homework, trying to check if matrix m is valid (each row has equal number of columns). (m, n) is retval.

Comment: @Gremo: The real problem is, that if haskell would guess, it could guess wrong and your program may be impredictable. But you can make the compiler guess by using typeclasses, but not in the way you want him.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Typeclasses aren't guessing, strictly speaking, as (afaik) type inference in (standard non-extended) Haskell must always yield *one* correct result for a given program, so there's only one type (class) that can be infered.

Comment: @delnan: That's what I mean by "But not in the way you want him". Typeclasses gives you the ability to use the same symbol for different functions - with the restriction, that the exact function must be derivable by the types of it's arguments and result type. Hm, this comment was misleading, maybe I just remove it.